# Comparison of time

Tags: java, java-time

I can't understand, or rather can't prove:

```
(isAfter(x) or isEquals(x)) == !isBefore(x)
```

and

```
(isBefore(x) or isEquals(x)) == !isAfter(x)
```

statements are allways true

with

```
default boolean isAfter(ChronoZonedDateTime<?> other) {
        long thisEpochSec = toEpochSecond();
        long otherEpochSec = other.toEpochSecond();
        return thisEpochSec > otherEpochSec ||
            (thisEpochSec == otherEpochSec && toLocalTime().getNano() > other.toLocalTime().getNano());
    }

default boolean isBefore(ChronoZonedDateTime<?> other) {
        long thisEpochSec = toEpochSecond();
        long otherEpochSec = other.toEpochSecond();
        return thisEpochSec < otherEpochSec ||
            (thisEpochSec == otherEpochSec && toLocalTime().getNano() < other.toLocalTime().getNano());
    }

default boolean isEqual(ChronoZonedDateTime<?> other) {
        return toEpochSecond() == other.toEpochSecond() &&
                toLocalTime().getNano() == other.toLocalTime().getNano();
    }
```

from `java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime;`

Comment: What exactly you expect from us?

Comment: (isAfter(x) or isEquals(x)) == !isBefore(x) and (isBefore(x) or isEquals(x)) == !isAfter(x) are true?

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What is the question?

Comment: @AxelH you are right if isBefore = thisEpochSec < otherEpochSec, isEqual == toEpochSecond() == other.toEpochSecond() and isAfter == thisEpochSec > otherEpochSec, but these functions are more complex

Comment: @andrey.ladniy These methods are simply comparing the time (in millisecond then in nanosecond if needed). Don't see what is complex. Then please explain your problem ...

Comment: @AxelH I tried prove that these statements are always true with boolean transformation based on functions code (not on names), but can't do this.

Comment: @andrey.ladniy they are not significantly more complex than what you say.  They just include the comparisons for the nanosecond part of the time as well if the whole second comparisons are equal.

Comment: @andrey.ladniy, I tried to explain simply one of the method, they used the same idea, based on their own condition

Comment: @andrey.ladniy By the way… The java.time framework is one place where you should *not* be generalizing to the interface. Instead you should stick with the concrete classes. So you should *not* be using `ChronoZonedDateTime` as [its JavaDoc explains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is whether you can prove that exactly one of `isBefore`, `isEqual`, and `isAfter` is true--yes, you can.

There are three possible comparisons between `this.toEpochSecond()` and `other.toEpochSecond()`: either `<`, `==`, or `>`.  Looking at the logic, it's clear that if the comparison is `<`, then `isBefore()` is true, and `isAfter()` and `isEqual()` are false, because the `>` and `==` comparisons on `toEpochSecond` will be false.  Likewise, if the comparison is `>`, then `isAfter()` is true, and `isBefore()` and `isEqual()` are false.  So in those two cases, the proposition holds.

What about the third case, where the `toEpochSecond` results are equal?  Then we compare `toLocalTime().getNano()`, which again can be `<`, `==`, or `>`.  If we look at how the code behaves when `toEpochSecond` results are equal and `getNano` results are compared, we find that in all three cases, exactly one of the methods returns true and the others return false.

So in essence, we've looked at five possible cases, and in all cases, exactly one of those three methods is true.  And since we've proven that, it follows that the statements in your original question:

```
(isAfter(x) or isEquals(x)) == !isBefore(x) 
(isBefore(x) or isEquals(x)) == !isAfter(x)
```

are also true.  QED

Comment: Thanks. My problem was in the approach to proof. I was tried to approve with boolean modifications, but not with finding possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

Read the condtion,

```
(isBefore(x) or isEquals(x)) == !isAfter(x)
```

if you are `before` or `equal` you are not `after`.

Example :

*If you are in second place or after, you can't be first.*

And if both condition are true, this mean you are either `before`, `equal` or `after`. Since you can't be `after` and `before` ( unless you are a cat in a box), you are `equal`.

## Code explanation

Those condition are quite simple, first it will try to compare the time in second with `toEpochSecond()`.

Then, depending on the method, it will check the nanoseconds value to be more precise. This part will depend on the method. Let take one :

```
default boolean isAfter(ChronoZonedDateTime<?> other) {
    long thisEpochSec = toEpochSecond();
    long otherEpochSec = other.toEpochSecond();
    return thisEpochSec > otherEpochSec ||
        (thisEpochSec == otherEpochSec && toLocalTime().getNano() > other.toLocalTime().getNano());
}
```

To check if `this` is after `other`, we need to check if the `this.seconds` is greater than `other.seconds`.

```
thisEpochSec > otherEpochSec
```

If not, it will go deeper and check to the nanoseconds only if the seconds are equals

```
thisEpochSec == otherEpochSec // seconds equals
    && toLocalTime().getNano() > other.toLocalTime().getNano());
```

Comment: I think you've missed the point (which is hard to get from the question, I know).  From the names, it _looks_ like exactly one of `isBefore`, `isEquals` or `isAfter` should be true.  But the OP wrote those methods, and he's having trouble proving that this is the case.  You can't argue that it must be true just by looking at the names.

Comment: @ajb, OP didn't write those, he said it came from (didn't check) `java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime;`. So this is not a code correction but a logic explanation for me. Might be wrong... EDIT : Plus, the condition shown are not code but pseudo-code, which means this is also a theorical question and not a code debug.

Comment: You're right, he didn't write them.  But it sounds to me like he's looking at the code and still isn't convinced.

Comment: @ajb, well, I have edited the answer with one small code review.